# Magento: Product thumb isn't loading, loading placeholder instead

Tags: magento

I am trying to get all product thumbs for a category product collection like that

```
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);

    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->setStoreId(1)
            ->setPageSize(10)
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    'status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            )
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
            ->addCategoryFilter($category);

    $productThumbs = array();

    try {
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $thumbUrl = $product->getThumbnailUrl(200, 60);

            $productThumbs[] = array(
                'entity_id' => $product->getId(),
                'thumb_url' => $thumbUrl
            );
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
```

It always return placeholder image urls like that...

```
http://magentohost/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/0/thumbnail/200x60/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong... Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that we need to load the `$product` before getting its thumb, like this

`$product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_id);`

and then we can retrieve its thumb using

`$thumbUrl = $product->getThumbnailUrl(200, 60);`